# getElementsByClassName( of node in template literal not working... - undefined error

Tags: javascript, dom, events, onclick, onload

I have an object of data retrieved via a GET request, which I'm then looping through and display in the DOM.

I then want to grab the ID of the `<i>` element, (which is a number from each element in the object), so I can then grab this ID and work with it and pass into another function, in another js file.  (Eventually, I'll be using this ID for a DELETE request).

Problem is, I run `getElementsByClassName` on the `i` tag, I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined`

When my data is injected into the DOM, I can see all the HTML tags/content there in the DOM through console.  However, it's almost as if the JavaScript maybe loading too quickly.

I've tried `setTimeOut()` function to bypass this.
`Window.onload = {}` and drop my function in here.
And even `addEventListener`.

However, the error still appears, regardless of what I try....

Any ideas?

**Here is snippets of my code below:**

```
  function displayLastTask(res) {
    const lastTask = (res[Object.keys(res).length-1]);

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(
          individualTasks +=
            `<div class="todoStyle">
                <div class="text">
                  <p>Date: ${lastTask.date}</p>
                  <p>Task: ${lastTask.todo}</p>
              </div>
              <div class-"icon">
                  <i class="far fa-calendar-times deleteButton" id=${lastTask.id}></i>
              </div>
            </div>`
        );
        tasksContainer.innerHTML = individualTasks;
        return tasksContainer;
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
```

**And here is the simple JS, I'm trying to grab the ID by:**

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('deleteButton');
for (var i = 0; i <= divs.length; i += 1) {
  divs[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.id);
  };
}
```

After the close the error in console. And copy and paste the code above into console, it works...

I cannot figure out, why any tag I try/className to grab, is returned undefined with the onclick combo, after the GET request is made and my data is posted into the DOM.

Comment: Did it get rendered on the DOM?

Comment: Please show us where `displayLastTask` is called, and how the code that installs the click handlers relates to it.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because of `getElementsByClassName('deleteButton')` execution before appending `deleteButton` to the dom, u can use `.then` method after calling the `displayLastTask` like this:

```
displayLastTask(res).then(() => {
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('deleteButton');
  for (var i = 0; i <= divs.length; i += 1) {
    divs[i].onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(this.id);
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you - this should work, but it doesn't as it's tied into an async function...   github.com/ReenaVerma/json-server

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined
    at dom-service.js:30
    at async Object.turnLoadingStateOn (dom-service.js:27)

Comment: @ReenaVerma so u can write `var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('deleteButton');` at dom-service.js:25 after `await displayLastTask(res);`

Comment: @ mohammadreza berneti - also returns the same error there too :)

Comment: @ReenaVerma u can pass wrap your codes in a function then pass it to the `displayLastTask` method and call it after binding new dom elements, this line `tasksContainer.innerHTML`.
Or bind a listener to the tasksContainer and check event target if the target element is `deleteButton` do something you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick is being attached too soon. Specifically, when you call `divs[i].onclick = function(e)`, your `div`s need to be in the DOM. However, it looks like they're not present when that loop runs, so the handlers are not attached.

You need to attach the onclick handlers after your GET request completes.

Comment: @Bergi Here's a link to my code/repo, so you can see this. Thank you:
https://github.com/ReenaVerma/json-server

Comment: @wentjun the DOM does get fully loaded, yes.